# Update the data of Async storage Key Automatically after login in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using `Async Storage` as state  management in react native i want to update the data of my `async` storage after login (automatically).... Currently i have data and it updates the data after a restart of app but i want to update it automatically after successfully. here is my code...

```
axios
        .post(
          ".../wp-json/api/v1/user/do_login",
          {
            username: username,
            password: password
          }
        )
        .then(async response => {
          if (response.data.type == "success") {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem(
              "full_name",
              response.data.profile.pmeta.full_name
            );
            await AsyncStorage.setItem(
              "user_type",
              response.data.profile.pmeta.user_type
            );
            await AsyncStorage.setItem(
              "profile_img",
              response.data.profile.pmeta.profile_img
            );
            await AsyncStorage.setItem(
              "profileBanner",
              response.data.profile.pmeta.banner_img
            );
            await AsyncStorage.setItem("profileType", response.data.type);
            await AsyncStorage.setItem(
              "projectUid",
              response.data.profile.umeta.id
            );
            await AsyncStorage.setItem(
              "projectProfileId",
              response.data.profile.umeta.profile_id
            );
            this.props.navigation.navigate("Home");

            //  NativeModules.DevSettings.reload();
          } else if (response.data.type == "error") {
            alert("Please Check Your Email / Password or Check Network ");
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
```

Comment: please be more specific in asking questions.

Comment: @NabeelK i can edit it can you please help about it

Comment: In my current situation my app is working fine but the issue is it requires refresh to update data. i want it as automatically.

Comment: Your question is too abrod, no idea what is wrong or nor working, please explain better. Also, take a look at [AsyncStorage.multiSet](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage/blob/LEGACY/docs/API.md#multiSet) to avoid alot of lines with `await` and `setItem`